# There exists $f \in C^2(\Bbb R^3,\Bbb R)$ such that $∆f=−3$ and $(0,0,0)$ is a local minimum.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

There exists $f\in \mathcal{C}^2\left (\mathbb{R}^3,\mathbb{R}\right )$ such that $\Delta f(x,y,z)=−3$ (Laplacian of $f(x,y,z)$), $\forall (x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3$ and $(0, 0, 0)$ local minimum.

How can I prove this true or false? I don't even know where to begin.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0):

Let $H$ be the Hessian matrix of $f$ at $(0, 0, 0)$. Since the trace of the Hessian is the Laplacian,
$$
\text{tr}(H) = \Delta{f}(0, 0, 0) = -3.
$$
Furthermore, since $f \in C^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{3}, \mathbb{R}),$ $H$ is symmetric, so we may by the spectral theorem diagonalize $H$ as $H = UDU^{T}$ where $D$ is diagonal and $U$ is orthogonal, that is, $U^{T}U = I$.
Using the identity $\text{tr}(UDU^{T}) = \text{tr}(D)$, we obtain
$$
\text{tr}(D) = \text{tr}(UDU^{T}) = \text{tr}(H) = -3.
$$
Since the diagonal entries of $D$ are precisely the eigenvalues of $H$, this means at least one of the eigenvalues of $H$ is negative. From this, we conclude that $(0, 0, 0)$ is not a local minimum of $f$ since a local minimum of $f$ is a point where the all the eigenvalues of the Hessian of $f$ are positive.